# navLinks.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am making a Responsive Navigation bar and i don't know what is the problem in the function. it should work because the `navLinks` is defined. So can anyone tell me what is the problem here?

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links li');
  //Toggle Nav 
  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
  });
  //Animate Links
  navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
    link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7}s`;
  });
}

navSlide();
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Add ```HTML``` code that contain ```nav-links``` as well..

Answer (score 0):

ok, i think you need for loop for each li then you can do it by using **$(selector).each**. In **$(this)** get control and **index** get index of control

```js
$(document).ready(function(){//Code for Each li
$('ul>li').each(function(index){console.log(this);console.log(index);});
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.each demo</title>
  <style>

  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
 
</body>
</html>
<script href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/core.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method returns the **first element** within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors whereas [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a **list of the document's elements** that match the specified group of selectors.

---

Since you want to retrieve all `li` elements and not just the first `li` element found inside the `.nav-links` element, just replace `querySelector()` with `querySelectorAll()` in your `navLinks` variable like this:

```
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` loops over arrays, and you are applying it to a single element

Use this instead:

`const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');`

Answer (score 0):

```
const navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links li');
```

This line has the error. 'querySelector' returns the first element that matches a CSS selector. But if you want to select all 'li' tags you have to use 'querySelectorAll()' instead.

Comment: The same answer has already been given by others.